# Product model numbers (SKU) missing on website front in OpenCart 3.0.2.0 (Theme Journal2)

Tags: model, opencart-3, sku

OpenCart 3.0.2.0 (Theme: Journal2)

Despite the fact that no actions were taken on the site, model numbers suddenly began to disappear. When I open the product list, the numbers are visible, but if you go to the next page of products, the numbers disappear. After, even if im goin back to first page of the list, SKU have disappered.

[Picture with steps what i do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNIZm.jpg)

Everything returns if i open category -> product list, and issue repeat if i click "next page" in product list.

Cache cleared - does't helped.

Comment: This is not Opencart issue. You should ask Journal theme developers directly, because theme is paid.

Comment: If this is a live site, can you send a link?